# some coffeescript not working, possibly related to application.js and/or javascript plugins

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am using an app that uses alot of javascript plugins, which could be the problem. I am trying to get the coffeescript to work, on the most basic page (home.html.erb) in the most basic way (hide a div). Coffeescript works in some parts of the app, but mostly not working.  Home.html.erb is part of the static_pages controller. The code below does not hide the div.  Any help would be appreciated

static_pages.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $("#rubyPic").hide()
  $("#heroMain").hide()
```

home.html.erb

```
<div class="center hero-unit" id="heroMain">
    <h1>finance </h1>
    <p>
    This is the home page for the RoR 
    </p>

</div>

<div class="box closable-chat-box">
  <div class="box-content padded">

    <h3>
        Your Classes that you are a currently signed up for 
        are below: 
    </h3>
    <section id="rubyPic">
      <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org' %>
      <%= render 'home_courses' %>
    </section>

  </div>
 </div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
//= require courses
//= require static_pages
//= require jquery191
//= require jqueryui1102
//= require fullcalendar/fullcalendar
//= require jquery_gritter
//= require sparkline
//= require tags_input
//= require jquery_uniform
//= require jquery.icheck
//= require select2
//= require d3
//= require xcharts
//= require bootstrap-wysihtml5
//= require justgage
//= require jquery.easy-pie-chart
//= require touchTouch
//= require dataTables
//= require responsive-tables
//= require wizard/bootstrap-wizard
//= require wizard/wizard_demo
//= require validation/jquery.validationEngine-en
//= require validation/jquery.validationEngine
//= require fullcalendar/calendar_events
//= require bootstrap-editable
//= require editable/editable_demo
//= require ibutton
//= require core_js/gritter
//= require core_js/calendar
//= require core_js/charts/xcharts_left_sine
//= require core_js/charts/xcharts_sine
//= require core_js/charts/xcharts_bar
//= require core_js/charts/sparkline_samples
//= require core_js/generic
//= require_tree .
```

gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'devise'
gem 'json', '~> 1.7.7'
gem 'activeadmin'

if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/i
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.9'
end


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', :github => 'guard/guard-spork'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: It could be a ton of things. Does the code run at all? Maybe you should [try some debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)?

Comment: Hmm, when I went to go to chrome dev tools through your link - I tried it out in Chrome and the div was hidden.  I went back to safari, and it was still there.   Do I have to clear cookies in safari when I use coffeescript?

Comment: Nope. Sounds like you need to google how to do debugging in Safari then :)

Comment: Also, some browsers perform very aggresive caching. Make sure that you always have the newest version of the script available in the browser when developing. (For example by adding a "cache breaker" parameter to the url like myscript.js?cache={randomNumberThatGetsUpdatedAtEachRequest}).

Comment: use '#/=' instead of '//='

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214246/renaming-application-js-to-application-js-coffee

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of these lines?

```
//= require jquery
...
//= require static_pages
//= require jquery191
```

Try remove line `//= require jquery191`?
Or replace `jquery` with it.
Or inculde `static_pages` at last.